# How to write nested route when function is not for member or collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a home_controller that has dozens of methods, none of which are on instances or collections of `Home`.  How can I write my routes in a block instead listing them in the following manner?:

```
put 'home/enable_admin', :as => :enable_admin
```

Comment: That's the most succinct way to define named routes that aren't tied to an instance or collection.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
resources :home, only: [] do
  member do
    #some route that does require an :id
  end
  collection do
    put 'enable_admin'
    #some route that doesn't require an :id
  end
end
```

This should give a bunch of custom routes with none of the normal rails routes.

Comment: That is what I'm after.  I'm coming to the conclusion it is not an option.

Comment: Sorry. Moved it from member to collection. This code should work. I'm not sure about your other routes, of course.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you want. Updated the answer.

Comment: I don't believe that will work, at least it isn't for me.  The path helper created `enable_admin_homes_path` returns `undefined local variable or method.`  I'm just going with what I've got.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeEssey No problem. When pasted into my routes file, it shows up as `enable_admin_home_index_path`. Not the nicest looking thing, but it is what it is.